# How to add current time in a datetime control if the time is not written

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, sqldatasource

I have a `GridView` and `SqlDataSource`,

I have a column type: `DateTime`. If I type only the date in the `TextBox`, then the time will be `00:00:00`. Is there any way of auto adding the current time if is not specified?

Thanks

Comment: Why add the current time to a user entered date?

Comment: Does this get displayed? Why not add it on the back end before it hits the database?

Comment: The user must add : dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm , but if he's only adding the dd.MM.yyyy then the time should be auto added , the current time

Comment: Server side or client side.  What if he has entered time?

Comment: this must be done client side , and if he has entered time then..nothing else should happen .

Comment: I forgot to mention , all this information are in a gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type only the date in the `TextBox` you can still submit and add the current time onto the Date.

```
DateTime inputDate = // However you are gathering the date ;
DateTime dateWithCurrentTime = inputDate.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

DateTime has an `Add` function that allows you to add a `TimeSpan` to get a new `DateTime` object.

If you add the current time of day (`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`) to the input you gathered, you will get a new `DateTime` object with the current time of day and the date that was input.

Answer (score 1):

Without any specific code, I can only answer your question vague but this might give you an Idea.

**Serverside Solution:** 
All in Code behind:

```
// To get the Time of right now 
DateTime oNow = DateTime.Today;

// Get your entered Time assuming it is Entered YYYY/MM/DD
string sEnteredDate = DateTextBox.Text;

// Edit the String to get Year, Month, Day
string sEnteredYear = sEnteredDate.Substring(0, 4);
string sEnteredMonth = sEnteredDate.Substring(5, 2);
string sEnteredDay = sEnteredDate.Substring(8, 2);

// Create final DateTime
DateTime oDateForDb = oNow;

oDateForDb.Day = sEnteredDay;
oDateForDb.Month = sEnteredMonth;
oDateForDb.Year = sEnteredYear;
```

Now oDateForDb should have the Date you want and the current hh:mm:ss.

Furthermore this whole concept should work just fine with Calender Extender or similar to guarantee that the Input is going to be the right DateFormat f.e. YYYY/MM/DD

---

EDIT:

**Client Side Solution**

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php

Do the same as Above only this time in jscript.